# Yammer API:Add admin programmatically

Tags: javascript, c#, yammer

Has anyone found a solution to assigning an added member as an admin programmatically? There are endpoints to add members but I haven't seen any that return admin info nor the ability to set that level privilege.

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported method of automating admin creation within Yammer.

When a Global Admin is added to O365 then that user automatically becomes a Verified Admin in Yammer. The creators of groups become a group admin automatically. Again, this is indirect and probably not what you hoped for.